# Render RadioButtonList using nested divs instead of tables or flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms, radiobuttonlist

I am generating a radio button list programatically in C#.NET 3.5 and using a `RadioButtonList` in order to do so. However, something I find very frustrating is the `RepeatLayout` property, which can only be set to `Flow` or `Table`.

Tables are for tabular data, not for displaying forms. And flow isn't helpful because it doesn't lend itself well to styling.

What I really want is a nest of divs I can address with CSS. Can this be done?

Some examples to illustrate what I'm talking about and example code below.

**Example of flow**

```
<span id="s1">
    <input id="s1_0" type="radio" value="Answer A" name="s1">
    <label for="s1_0">Answer A</label>
    <br>
    <input id="s1_1" type="radio" value="Answer B" name="s1">
    <label for="s1_1">Answer B</label>
</span>
```

**Example of table**

```
<table border="0" id="s1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" value="Answer A" name="s1" id="s1_0"><label for="s1_0">Answer A</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" value="Answer B" name="s1" id="s1_1"><label for="s1_1">Answer B</label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**What I actually want**

```
<div id="s1">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="Answer A" name="s1" id="s1_0">
        <label for="s1_0">Answer A</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="Answer B" name="s1" id="s1_1">
        <label for="s1_1">Answer B</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**C# Code I'm using to generate the list**

I know whatever the solution is, won't be as quick and easy as this, but I'm putting it here so you can get an idea of the context in which I'm using it.

```
RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList { RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Table };
foreach (ControlValue cv in MasterControl.listControlValues)
{
    rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem(cv.name, cv.value));
}
ControlContainer.Controls.Add(rbl);
```

Comment: I also note that .NET 4.5 has Unordered List and Ordered List options, which is far better. But doesn't help me here :( (using 3.5)

Comment: if you want to restrict on `radioButtonList` I don't think it is possible to disaply `list-item` in seperate div's. But you can you individual `radion-button` with `group name` and set your each `radio-button` where you please

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use [WebControlAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adapters.webcontroladapter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to change the way of how `RadioButtonList` is rendered.

Below is the complete code for your case:

```
public class RadioButtonListAdapter : WebControlAdapter
{
    protected override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag("div");
    }

    protected override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        var adaptedControl = (RadioButtonList) Control;
        int itemCounter = 0;

        writer.Indent++;
        foreach (ListItem item in adaptedControl.Items)
        {
            var inputId = adaptedControl.ClientID + "_" + itemCounter++;

            // item div
            writer.RenderBeginTag("div");
            writer.Indent++;

                // input
                writer.AddAttribute("type", "radio");
                writer.AddAttribute("value", item.Value);
                writer.AddAttribute("name", adaptedControl.ClientID);
                writer.AddAttribute("id", inputId);

                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    writer.AddAttribute("checked", "checked");
                }

                writer.RenderBeginTag("input");
                writer.RenderEndTag();

                // label
                writer.AddAttribute("for", inputId);

                writer.RenderBeginTag("label");

                writer.Write(item.Value);

                writer.RenderEndTag();

            // div
            writer.Indent--;
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }
        writer.Indent--;
    }
}
```

To connect this adapter to you application you have two options. First is to do it programmatically in page **constructor**:

```
var adapters = Context.Request.Browser.Adapters;
var radioButtonListType = typeof(RadioButtonList).AssemblyQualifiedName;
var adapterType = typeof(RadioButtonListAdapter).AssemblyQualifiedName;
if (!adapters.Contains(radioButtonListType))
{
    adapters.Add(radioButtonListType, adapterType);
}
```

Second option is using `.browser` file:

Add new `Browser File` to your project. It will reside in `App_Browsers` folder. Then replace contents with following declaration:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
            <controlAdapters>
                <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList" 
                         adapterType="<your namespace>.RadioButtonListAdapter" />
            </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

As a reference you can use links from ScottGu's post [ASP.NET 2.0 Control Adapter Architecture](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/21/asp-net-2-0-control-adapter-architecture.aspx) they can give a good basement in this topic.

Also there is an open source [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/) project that adresses some of rendering issues of default ASP.NET controls.

Answer (score 1):

For .net 4.5 >

You can get almost that html, at least the structure using OrderedList (or UnOrdered), and then play around with CSS to get your preferred style.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="OrderedList">
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Option 1"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Option 2"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Option 3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This will render the html:

```
<ol id="rblTest">
    <li>
        <label for="rblTest_0">Option 1</label>
        <input id="rblTest_0" type="radio" name="rblTest" value="0">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="rblTest_1">Option 2</label>
        <input id="rblTest_1" type="radio" name="rblTest" value="0">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="rblTest_2">Option 2</label>
        <input id="rblTest_2" type="radio" name="rblTest" value="0">
    </li>
</ol>
```

Setting TextAlign="Right" gives you the label after the input if you'd rather want that.

This is as close as you can get to your setup with div's but then again, surround the whole list with a div and set the li and label css from that div and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should look for a workaround with CSS rather than changing the structure. Even I face some problems with this sort of structure but my designing team fixes it with ease.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm going to do in this case, simply because of time constraints. The actual styling isn't the problem; it's easy enough to apply CSS to a table. The problem is that we're using a table to display something that isn't tabular data. It also presents an absolute nightmare for anyone using a screen reader.